A serious security issue in remote data storage
In order to ensure the integrity of remote data, Ateniese et al. first proposed the idea of provable data possession (PDP). In this proof, the data are computed as elements on a G-group in the form of the following formula
$\sigma=\left(H\left(i\right) \cdot g^{m}\right)^{sk}$
, and when verifying, computing this formula
$e\!\left(\sigma, g\right)\!\!=\!\!e(H\!\left(i\right)\cdot g^{m},pk)$
will check the integrity of the remote outsourced data.
However, if the prover only stores the values of ( m ) mapped to the ( Z ) group without storing the original ( m ), verification is still possible. The elements we usually select are 160 bits in size, which is much smaller than the original data size. This is very space-efficient for remote storage providers.
So, how can I defend against this type of attack?
